# How to disable app authenticity on IBM MobileFirst 7.1 remote server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Is there any way to disable app authenticity on remote mobile first server? In worklight 6.2 we can manually disable app authenticity on console but cannot find the same settings in mobilefirst 7.1.

As a workaround: We are using custom security test in authenticationConfig.xml and haven't used app authenticity test realm in it. The surprise in the workaround is that it still shows basic app authenticity enabled on the mobile first console. Any pointers for the workaround dilemma as well?

Appreciate any inputs!

Code:

```
<customSecurityTest name="LoginAdapter-securityTest">
        <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="1"/>
        <test realm="SingleSignonRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="2"/>
    </customSecurityTest>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when i deploy a wlapp of a previous version of worklight (6.1) on MobileFirst Server 7.1.

A workaround is to remove the `<security />`entry in application-descriptor.xml

Example for a iphone app.

Initially the application-descriptor.xml was the following :

```
<iphone bundleId="com.WorklightStarterjQueryMobile" version="1.0">
    <worklightSettings include="true"/>
    <security />
</iphone>
```

And App Authenticity Configuration was "Basics"

Now i use this one (removed security entry):

```
<iphone bundleId="com.WorklightStarterjQueryMobile" version="1.0">
    <worklightSettings include="true"/>
</iphone>
```

And App Authenticity Configuration is now "none"

Answer (score 1):

Starting MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 there is now basic authenticity and extended authenticity modes. There is no more disabled/serving/serving-blocking options via a dropdown in the MobileFirst Console.

The way to disable Application Authenticity Protection is to remove its realm from the security test in the authenticationConfig.xml file and then re-deploy the .war file, otherwise the changes will not be in effect.

Comment: Thanks idan, As mentioned we were not using app authenticity realm in SecurityTest but still it shows the basic authenticity in console. is there any other configuration that we have to look into?

Comment: The only reason for that is would be that you have an incorrectt war deployed

Comment: We have checked the authenticationconfig.xml file by unzipping the war file and it doesn't have app authenticity realm tag in it.

Comment: My only suggestion is that you will re-build the war in studio (or however you build it) and make sure that there it is also commented out everywhere and re-deploy the new .war, and see if it is enabled still.

Comment: After disabling app authenticity it still shows the basic app authenticity for iOS and android app, but for windows it shows the app authenticity as none. Not sure why this difference in different environments after disabling app authenticity.

Comment: What is your exact 7.1 build number? I will test with the same build that you are using.

Comment: We are using 7.1.0.00-20150907-1904

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'll be able to test this only next week. You know the procedure by now. If this is extremely important for you then you can open a PMR.