# Cannot login to app on iOS actural Device MobileFirst Project

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

Hi I recently had develop small sample application using IBM MobileFirst 7.1. I have successfully run app on simulator, it able to login perfectly without error but when I tested on actual device (iOS 9.2) the app failed to login here is some error log I receive

```
    2016-02-16 15:31:39.847 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:221 :: Sending request (http://10.12.11.59:10080/YITCallCenter/authorization/v1/clients/instance) with headers: 
{
    "Accept-Language" = "th-TH";
    "User-Agent" = "YITCallCenter/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 9.2.1; Scale/3.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
    "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
    "x-wl-app-version" = "1.0";
    "x-wl-device-id" = "AACA3EB7-EEF1-429A-A9A7-597231D2C8B2";
    "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0";
}
You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs.
2016-02-16 15:31:39.855 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:332 :: Starting the request with URL http://10.12.11.59:10080/YITCallCenter/authorization/v1/clients/instance
2016-02-16 15:31:39.857 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:231 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x155d04d90>{number = 1, name = main})
2016-02-16 15:31:39.860 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '98.279053' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-02-16 15:31:39.933 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:345 :: Request Success
2016-02-16 15:31:39.935 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:346 :: Response Status Code : 200
2016-02-16 15:31:39.938 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/01/25 08:04:23
2016-02-16 15:31:39.942 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFinished:] in WLRequest.m:365 :: Response Header: {
    "Content-Length" = 887;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Tue, 16 Feb 2016 08:32:14 GMT";
    "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0";
}
Response Data: {"certificate":"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"}
Status code=200
2016-02-16 15:31:39.944 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFinished:] in WLRequest.m:424 :: NSS object is null
2016-02-16 15:31:39.948 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] BOOL hasCertificateExpired(X509 *) in WLCertManager.m:647 :: Certificate currentDate: 2016-02-16 08:31:39 +0000, expiryDate: 1523-02-16 08:32:15 +0000
2016-02-16 15:31:39.951 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [WARN] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] BOOL hasCertificateExpired(X509 *) in WLCertManager.m:649 :: Certificate has expired. Certificate expired on: 1523-02-16 08:32:15 +0000, verified on: 2016-02-16 08:31:39 +0000
2016-02-16 15:31:39.954 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager failRegistratioWithResponse:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:866 :: Response does not contain a valid certificate and client Id. device registration failed
2016-02-16 15:31:39.967 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed.
2016-02-16 15:31:39.978 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed.
2016-02-16 15:31:39.986 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/01/25 08:04:23
2016-02-16 15:31:40.001 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] -[NotificationEx loadingStop:] in NotificationEx.m:150 :: Loading stop
2016-02-16 15:31:40.002 YITCallCenter[3010:1042149] [DEBUG] [NONE] Client registration failed with error: {"responseHeaders":{},"status":200,"responseText":"Invalid response when registering application","invocationContext":null}
2016-02-16 15:31:40.005 YITCallCenter[3010:1042108] [ERROR] [NONE] [/apps/services/api/YITCallCenter/iphone/query] failure. state: 200, response: undefined
2016-02-16 15:31:40.088 YITCallCenter[3010:1041692] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '84.625732' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

I think the most interesting error is

```
[WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager failRegistratioWithResponse:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:866 :: Response does not contain a valid certificate and client Id. device registration failed
```

PS I have already set ipaddress instead of localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out there bug on Mobile First itself it turn out that when I set my iPhone calendar buddhist to Gregorian the application able to login. Recommended IBM to come out with patch Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact problem with all of my upgraded 7.1 iOS mobilefirst applications.  I discovered that the App Authenticity was turned on to Basic for iOS by default now (new in MobileFirst 7.1) because I had an existing  section in my application-descriptor.xml. Removing the security section from my application-descriptor.xml and rebuilding and redeploying the wlapp files fixed my problem. I followed this approach.

[How to disable app authenticity on IBM MobileFirst 7.1 remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591267/how-to-disable-app-authenticity-on-ibm-mobilefirst-7-1-remote-server)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try the following, as mentioned in this answer: [Unable to login to app on device or simulator after upgrade to iOS 9 and MobileFirst 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237715/unable-to-login-to-app-on-device-or-simulator-after-upgrade-to-ios-9-and-mobilef)

Update the host value in worklight.plist to match the one of the server you attempt to connect to. Then see if it fails still.